# My Childhood in 11 letters!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

**2 6 4 9 1 5 9 9 7**

The word/group of words is __________?

Everyone is familiar with this (I guess).

Hint 1

> The numbers are (somehow) associated with the position of the letters in the English alphabet.

Hint 2

> M = 4

Comment: Could be I M A G I N A T I O N?

Comment: :( nopeeeee !!! wait i'll add a hint!

Comment: 11 letters, but only 9 numbers. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Glorfindel yep yep yep!!!

Comment: I've a feeling it's related to the normal phone numpad..but even if i'm correct it'll be hard to guess, seeing everyone might have a different childhood :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you associate the numbers 1 to 9 with the alphabet, like below

> $\array{~1&~2&~3&~4&~5&~6&~7&~8&~9\\A&B&C&D&E&F&G&H&I\\J&K&L&M&N&O&P&Q&R\\S&T&U&V&W&X&Y&Z&\&}$

then the numbers, with a little choice, give

> “Tom & Jerry”,
> and these two names give the 11 letter classic cartoon, *Tom and Jerry*.

Comment: Haha You got the answer! well done! my reasoning is just a another form of your reasoning! but still its absolutely correct!!!!!

Comment: oh i almost forgot!!! '&' (ampersand) is the 27th letter of the alphabet!!

Answer (score 3):

This is perhaps going to be "too broad".
One possible answer -

> Substitution code, where:
>  1 = B
>  2 = N
>  4 = S
>  5 = L
>  6 = O
>  7 = D
>  9 = E
>
>   which gives:
>  `2 6 4 9 1 5 9 9 7`
>  `N O S E B L E E D`
>
>  a childhood experience, *very* common for some, everyone is familiar with (I guess).

Comment: :( nope that isnt the answer but well tried!  i'll give you a vote :)

Comment: (@starkgurl - Other than it not being the answer in your head, there's no particularly apparent reason in the puzzle to indicate it's wrong.- hence, "too broad".  You may want to add something to give the puzzle a clearer path to a solution, or more clearly defined boundaries.)

Comment: It is wrong, im sorry to say. Please read all the clues in the question before commenting :) thanks

Comment: I think it's supposed to be an 11 letter word somehow - also you have 0 - E not 9 - E.